# jQuery UI Datepicker onClose: distinguish between date click and document click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker with an onClose function that is called when user select a date (correct), but also when the calendar is shown but user clicks anywhere in the document (wrong).

Inside onClick, is there a way to distinguish between user's click on a date (then calendar is closed) and user's click in the document?

```
$( "#datePicker" ).datepicker({
    ...
    onClose: myFunction(),
    ...
});
```

The same calendar is used in 2 ways:

- sometimes user can select a day (click on a day -> myFunction() must be called)
- sometimes user must select a month (select month -> click 'ok' button
  -> myFunction() must be called)

I tried use 'onSelect': it works only when user clicks on a day, but myFunction isn't called when calendar is "select month mode"

thanks.

This is the code I tried with @Prashant Kumar solution:

```
  my={};

(function(){
    my.customCalendar={     

        closedBySelect:false,
        init: function()
        {
            $( "#datePicker" ).datepicker({
                ...
                onSelect: function () {
                    my.customCalendar.myFunction();
                    this.closedBySelect = true;
                },              
                onClose: function (){
                    console.log('fired on close');
                    if (this.closedBySelect) {
                        console.log('logic when closed on select');
                        this.myFunction();
                    } else {
                     console.log('logic when closed on document click');
                    }
                    my.customCalendar.closedBySelect = false;
                },
                ...
                showButtonPanel: true
            });

            ...

            myFunction:function (dateText, inst)
            {
                ...
            },

            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        closedBySelect:false,
        onSelect: function (date, options) {
            alert('fired when selected');
            options.settings.closedBySelect = true;
        },
        onClose: function (date, options) {
            alert('fired on close');
            if (options.settings.closedBySelect) {
                console.log('logic when closed on select');
            } else {
             console.log('logic when closed on document click');
            }
            options.settings.closedBySelect = false;
        }
    });
});
```

closedBySelect is not in the API rather it is a custom attribute added which we can easily be set in all events of datepicker :)

Update Code   :

Used slightly different approach here -

```
$(function () { 
    var datePicker = $('#datepicker');
    datePicker.data('closedOn','document').datepicker({
        showButtonPanel:true,       
        onClose: function (date, options) {          
            alert($(this).data('closedOn'));  
            //  your logic goes here ...
            $(this).data('closedOn','document');
        }
    }).datepicker('widget').on('mousedown',function(event){
        var $this = $(this);
        var target = $(event.target);      
        if(target.hasClass('ui-datepicker-close'))
        {
            console.log('closed from button panel');
           datePicker.data('closedOn','byButtonPanel');
        }
        if( typeof target.parent().data('month') != 'undefined')
        {
            console.log('closed by selecting date');
            datePicker.data('closedOn','byDateSelect');
        }      
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. I was thinking too about a variable to set true or false, but sure not a nice solution like yours. 
Unluckily it doesn't work because when I select a month then i press 'ok' button onSelect isn't called so closedBySelect stays false and 'logic when closed on document click' is called: I need set closedBySelect true when I clcik 'ok' button ;

Comment: oh ok. could you please paste your code whatever you tried so far.

Comment: apologies for the late reply . Added the code above :)