# JQuery datepicker defaults to todays date when enter key is pressed on empty textbox

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Whenever enter key is pressed on datepicker textbox, today's date is populated.
This behavior can be seen on [Jquery Datepicker site](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). Also, if i type a random text like 34123123123 and hit enter, it resolve's to current date.
I want to avoid this behavior. I tried to handle it using the below code but no luck..

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker().keydown(function (event) {   

    if(event.which === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER)
    {
        event.preventDefault();     
        console.log("enter key pressed " + $(this).val());        
        return false;
    }
});
```

Any suggestions to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried the keyup event?

Comment: Plugins usually use keyup instead of keydown.

Comment: Or hey, take a look at http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate -- you are getting that as a return on enter. Simply change that to what you might want.

Comment: And a possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668325/jquery-datepicker-no-default-date

Answer (score 0):

While in an earlier incarnation of this i naively said "use the tools you're given," you may need to extend them.

Kind of a "huh" moment. Basically, what you're looking to do is, when the datePicker widget closes, determine whether the date was chosen by clicking on a date or by the user typing something into the field. So here's something that will tell you that. I've taken some of this from **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703745/jquery-ui-datepicker-onclose-distinguish-between-date-click-and-document-click)**, in terms of determining where the datepicker's close event was triggered, but the onClose function itself had to be rewritten to suit your use case, as far as I can understand it.

```js
$(function() {
  var datePicker = $('#datepicker');
  datePicker.data('closedOn', 'document').datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    onClose: function(date, options) {
      //  your logic goes here ...
      var dateEl = $(this);
      // so we either clicked out of the date select or we hit enter
      //   in the input. In this case we should use the data-oldValue
      //   we've been building in the keyup/blur trigger for the input.
      //
      if (dateEl.data('closedOn') == 'document') {
        // if the user has entered MANUALLY a valid format date...
        if(Date.parse(dateEl.data("oldValue")) ) {
          console.log("Manually entered a valid date!");
          dateEl.val(dateEl.data("oldValue"));
        } else {
          console.log("Not a valid date format...")
          dateEl.val("");
        }
      } else {
        // Here, the user has clicked on a date in the calendar widget.
        //  If there were some sort of desired processing, that could
        //  happen here.
      }
    }
  }).on("keyup", function(){
    $(this).data("oldValue", $(this).val() );
})
  .datepicker('widget').on('mousedown', function(event) {
  /***
   * Listener to detect if the user
   *  has closed the calendar by clicking
   *  on a given date, or by any other means.
   *  This will tell us if the date was changed
   *  by the date picker, or manually.
   ***/
    var $this = $(this);
    var target = $(event.target);
    // If the button panel is enabled, and the user has
    //  clicked there...
    if (target.hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
      datePicker.data('closedOn', 'byButtonPanel');
    };
    // Or if the user has clicked on a given date in the
    //  calendar widget...
    if (typeof target.parent().data('month') != 'undefined') {
      datePicker.data('closedOn', 'byDateSelect');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: Crap. Or not. I just completely defeated the point of the datepicker. You're going to want to filter the content of the enter somehow.